# Jquery Issue with dynamic id's

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am using dynamic id's for each row of a table and I want to display data in an alert box corresponding to a clicked element. To do this, I have written the following code.

```
<%i = 1%>
   <% count = @user_rep.count%>
   <% @user_rep.each do |result| %>
   <tr>
       <td><%=h result.user%></td>
       <td><%=h result.nodeip%></td>
<td><%=link_to_function result.time,:id => "log_#{i}",:onclick => "set_file(#{i},'#{result.user}','#{result.nodeip}')" %></td>
<% i = i + 1 %>
<div id = 'file'>
<div id = 'image'>
<%= link_to_function image_tag("play_images.jpeg",:width => 30, :height => 30,:align => 'left', :title => 'Play'),:id => 'play'%></div>
<%= link_to_function image_tag("images.jpeg",:align => 'right'), :id => 'close'%>
<div id = 'request'>
</div> 
</div>
</tr>
<%end%>
```

I will display table with tha last coloumn displying link button. When we click on this link, a div "file" will be shown in which a link button play is there. On clicking it, i want to display the user and node in concatenated form. I m using this jquery.

```
function set_file(id,user,node)
{
var filename = time+"_"+user+"_"+node+"_"+activity;
jQuery("#log_"+id).ready(function() {
      jQuery("#file").show("slow");
        });
 jQuery("#close").click(function() {
          jQuery("#file").hide("slow");
        });
 jQuery("#play").click(function() {
   alert(filename);
       });
```

But when the first page loads, it displays the alert box with the correct user name node. But when I click on another link of the table and then click on the *play* link button, it displays the alert box with the previous string and when I click on OK in the alert box it displays the current clicked string. The value of the filename (variable) stays unchanged.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it's a basic use case for delegation

Comment: Please ignore "var filename = time+"_"+user+"_"+node+"_"+activity;" It is var filename = user+"_"+node;

Comment: @apneadiving How can i implement it?

Comment: Hey I dont want to display alert box more n more. I want it to b display only once with correct value

Comment: do your html elements share the same html ids (several #file, #close, #play, etc ) ? Shouldn't they have specific id (play_i) that you may use to bind your events ?

Comment: It can't help that your html is invalid. Don't nest div elements directly into table or tr elements. (And as jbl mentioned, don't include duplicate ids.)

Comment: @jbl No i didnt take specific id for all. but if I do this then how can i differentiate CSS?

Comment: ids MUST be unique. For css, you have class attribute and css selectors. Tidy up your html (see also @nnnnnn comment), is the first thing you have to do.

Comment: Hey I defined unique IDs. But CSS is not working. how can i define CSS for id play_1 play_2 as a common one?

Comment: this is very basic css question, out of scope of your jQuery question. You should take a look at css classes.

Comment: Heyy guyz.. thanks a lot... I did this...;-))